# Center Coordinate in Google Map iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

in iOS's MapKit we have a property that returns center of the map's coordinate.

```
    mapView.centerCoordinate.latitude
    mapView.centerCoordinate.longitude
```

is there a way to do this in Google's Map Sdk for iOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here `mapView` is `GMSMapView`. You need to user `projection` property of google map.

```
let lat = mapView.projection.coordinate(for: mapView.center).latitude
let lng = mapView.projection.coordinate(for: mapView.center).longitude

print("center Lat & Lng = \(lat), \(lng)")
```